# Does "docker-compose down" invoke "docker stop" on each container?

Tags: docker

I've written a Python program which ensures that its threads are gracefully stopped upon receiving a Unix SIGTERM signal. I understand that [docker stop](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) sends a SIGTERM request to the main process inside the container, and after a grace period, SIGKILL. The documentation for [docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) states that it "stops containers", but does not say explicitly how. I assume that it calls `docker stop` on each container?

Comment: see https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/project.py  `operator.methodcaller('stop', **options),` and https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/cli/signals.py  shows it uses SIGINT and SIGTERM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the links given by [user2915097](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915097/user2915097), it seems that this is indeed the case. The `down` method of the `Project` class invokes its `stop` method, which in terms seems to iterate over the containers and call `stop` on each one.

Answer (score 2):

**NPM and Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT: Just Don't**

I'm going to add this here so it is documented somewhere that some one else finds this answer too.

Node.JS Express + MongoDB app using Docker Compose. Pretty basic BUT it does not trigger the `SIGINT` or the `SIGTERM` events.

https://github.com/neozenith/hello-mongo/tree/4c1c3d9a55b574ba5a1c5f45dbf708c65a70c434

**Solution**

https://github.com/neozenith/hello-mongo/commit/c7e1b7497f204ffaa9387f99cb88188dadc1c094

*BEFORE:*

```
# WAS THIS
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

*AFTER*:

```
# FUN FACT: DO NOT RUN ["npm", "start"] as the ENTRYPOINT
# It does not forward the SIGTERM and SIGINT events to Node
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

The exec form of `ENTRYPOINT` sends through the `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` to PID 1.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example

The key here is that `npm` does not forward that to `node`